# Form not updating Database with Select Tag Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently added a new column to my table in the database called "sport". I am trying to update the value in the column using a select_tag in a form however everytime I have tried the data has not updated. The rest of the form is currently working and updating correctly.

The select tag is currently implemented like this inside my view.

```
<%= f.label :sport %>
<%= select_tag(:sport, options_for_select([['Basketball', 1], ['NRL', 2], ['Super Rugby', 3], ['AFL', 4], ['eSports', 5], ['Ice Hockey', 6], ['Horse Racing', 7], ['Tennis', 8], ['NFL', 9] ]))%>
```

:sport is declared as an integer within the table.

The controller currently looks like this:

```
class BetsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @bet = Bet.new
  end

  def create
    @bets = Bet.new(bet_params)

    if @bets.save
        flash[:success] = 'Bet Successfull Logged.'
        redirect_to new_bet_path
      else
        flash[:danger] = 'Error, Bet has not been logged. Try again mate.'
        redirect_to new_bet_path
      end
  end

  def show
    @bet = Bet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @bet = Bet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @bet = Bet.find(params[:id])

        if @bet.update_attributes(bet_params)
            flash[:success] = "Bet Updated!"
            redirect_to bet_path(params[:id])
        else
            render action: :edit
        end
  end

  private

    def bet_params
      params.require(:bet).permit(:bet_placed, :game, :units_placed, :odds, :profit_or_loss, :date_of_bet, :resolved, :push, :sport, :bookmaker)
    end

end
```

Comment: when you submit the form: what params are submitted to the controller. What type is the new column?

Comment: The type of the new column is an integer.
The entire form is submmited for the Bet row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bet if you check your params hash you'll notice the info isn't there.
Try using the `select` form_for helper, instead of the `select_tag` helper.  Instead you code might look something like:

```
<%= f.select(:title, collection: [['Basketball', 1], ['NRL', 2], ['Super Rugby', 3], ['AFL', 4], ['eSports', 5], ['Ice Hockey', 6], ['Horse Racing', 7], ['Tennis', 8], ['NFL', 9] ])%>
```